# Generating random number strings on the same page

Tags: javascript, string, random, numbers

I'm trying to add about 20 separate random generated number strings between 55 and 999 on a single page, is this possible? I have tried appending the element ID from "randomnumber" to randomnumber2, 3, 4, 5, etc..." without success. Any ideas?

I have tried to change this script to fit my needs, but it doesnt seem to work more than once.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = generateRandomNumber;
 function generateRandomNumber(){
     var n = 999;
     var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
 document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<class id="randomNumber"></class>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
<head>

<script>
window.onload = generateRandomNumber;

     var n = 4000;
     var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number5 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number6 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number7 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number8 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number9 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number10 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number11 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number12 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number13 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number14 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number15 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number16 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number17 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
     var number18 = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;



function generateRandomNumber(){
document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
document.getElementById("randomNumber2").innerHTML = number2;
document.getElementById("randomNumber3").innerHTML = number3;
document.getElementById("randomNumber4").innerHTML = number4;
document.getElementById("randomNumber5").innerHTML = number5;
document.getElementById("randomNumber6").innerHTML = number6;
document.getElementById("randomNumber7").innerHTML = number7;
document.getElementById("randomNumber8").innerHTML = number8;
document.getElementById("randomNumber9").innerHTML = number9;
document.getElementById("randomNumber10").innerHTML = number10;
document.getElementById("randomNumber11").innerHTML = number11;
document.getElementById("randomNumber12").innerHTML = number12;
document.getElementById("randomNumber13").innerHTML = number13;
document.getElementById("randomNumber14").innerHTML = number14;
document.getElementById("randomNumber15").innerHTML = number15;
document.getElementById("randomNumber16").innerHTML = number16;
document.getElementById("randomNumber17").innerHTML = number17;
document.getElementById("randomNumber18").innerHTML = number18;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<class id="randomNumber"></class>
<class id="randomNumber2"></class>
<class id="randomNumber3"></class>
<class id="randomNumber4"></class>
<class id="randomNumber5"></class>
<class id="randomNumber6"></class>
<class id="randomNumber7"></class>
<class id="randomNumber8"></class>
<class id="randomNumber9"></class>
<class id="randomNumber10"></class>
<class id="randomNumber11"></class>
<class id="randomNumber12"></class>
<class id="randomNumber13"></class>
<class id="randomNumber14"></class>
<class id="randomNumber15"></class>
<class id="randomNumber16"></class>
<class id="randomNumber17"></class>
<class id="randomNumber18"></class>



 </body>
```